# Visual Studio Code autocomplete starts from bottom of list instead of known properties

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently when I'm launching autocomplete (a.k.a. in VS Code `Intellisense`) via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Space</kbd>  my suggestion list is presented from the very bottom of list (note the slider position):

[image]

Usually at this place absolutely non-matching properties are placed so I have not much help from suggestions in such case. VS Code has good knowledge on shape and form of types I'm working with (it's written in `TypeScript`) so it's expected to present known properties as first (at top of suggestion list)
Does anyone know hot to fix such issue?

This seems to occur at random places, in approximately 70% of hits it's presenting correct list (starting from top)

Answer (score 27):

Configuring the settings should solve the issue:

```
{
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
}
```

More about how to customize IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code: [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense)

Comment: Who thinks suggesting random element at middle of the suggesting list instead of known properties is a good idea??? Thanks!

Comment: Checking-in in 2021

Comment: "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom"